# How to identify 2 specific variables in a pandas column and perform caps on the 2nd letter of the variables only

Tags: python, pandas, capitalize

I have a column of data in a pandas dataframe and I wanted to only capitalize the 2nd letters for 2 of the variables in the column. E.g. I only want to capitalize "Et Appeal" to "ET Appeal" and "Ip Application" to "IP Application" while leaving the rest of the variables unchanged.

How do I iterate over each row in that specific column and variables and thereafter return the dataframe with the capitalization?

I have defined a function as follows:

```
def capitalize_nth(s):
    return s[0] + s[1].capitalize() + s[2:]
```

[Column Data in pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCunT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky but works for what you need:

```py
>>> s = pd.Series(['Ip Application', 'Et Appeal', 'Enquiry on situation', 'Stolen', 'Waiver for goods'])
>>> [x[0] + x[1].upper() + x[2:] if len(x.split()[0]) == 2 else x for x in s]
['IP Application', 'ET Appeal', 'Enquiry on situation', 'Stolen', 'Waiver for goods']
```